# Remove gap with gridspec

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

Im trying to remove this gap using gridspec, any hints?

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))

gs = GridSpec(2,2, hspace=0, figure=fig)
gs1 = GridSpec(2,2, figure=fig, hspace=0, height_ratios = [10,1])


ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,1])

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=None, hspace=None)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[1,:])
```

[image]

Comment: I don’t think that code can completely reproduce that result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the first GridSpec with two rows, which is giving the gap. You can keep all three subplots as part of the same grid and adjust the heights of each row/column. Adjust the `figsize` and `height_ratios` to see the right shaped figures. Hope this helps...

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
gs = GridSpec(2,2, figure=fig, height_ratios = [4,1])
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,1])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,:])
```

[image]